# How to set hosting environment name for .NET Core console app using Generic Host (HostBuilder)

Tags: c#, .net-core

I am setting up a .NET Core 2.x console app as a Windows service and need to load an appsettings json file based on the environment.  I was thinking to start the service with a command line argument that identifies the environment.  How can I do that in Visual Studio?  No matter what I set in the project settings, the EnvironmentName value is always "Production".

How can I set my environment from a command line argument?

```
var hostBuilder = new HostBuilder()
                 .UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
                 .ConfigureAppConfiguration((hostingContext, config) =>
                 {
                     var env = hostingContext.HostingEnvironment;
                     config.AddCommandLine(args);
                     config.AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{env.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true);
                     config.AddEnvironmentVariables();
                 })
                 .ConfigureServices((hostContext, services) =>
                 {
                     //Inject additional services as needed
                     services.AddHostedService<JobRunner>();
                });
```

[image]

Comment: For .net 5.0, see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/generic-host?view=aspnetcore-5.0#host-configuration

It discusses how IHostEnvironment setting EnvironmentName is determined by the generic host builder.  Note how prefixes are used for the environment variable provider.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

You can set the environment from the command line variables via the [`ConfigureHostConfiguration`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.hosting.hostbuilder.configurehostconfiguration) extension method.

> Set up the configuration for the builder itself. This will be used to
> initialize the Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.IHostEnvironment for use
> later in the build process.

```
var hostBuilder = new HostBuilder()
    .UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
    .ConfigureHostConfiguration(configurationBuilder => {
        configurationBuilder.AddCommandLine(args);
    })
    .ConfigureAppConfiguration((hostingContext, cfg) =>
    {
        // ...

        var env = hostingContext.HostingEnvironment;
        Console.WriteLine(env.EnvironmentName); // Test
        // ...
    });
    
    // ...

    hostBuilder.Build();
```

---

In Visual Studio, you configure the application arguments with the same ones as being used by `dotnet run` which is **`--environment`**,
e.g. `dotnet run --environment Test`.

Without this application argument, the hosting environment defaults back to `Production`.

[image]

Comment: That works perfect.  Now I just need to get those same arguments passed in via the windows service start parameters.

Comment: I've stumbled over so many possible answers that just make me cringe. I'm so glad I found this. It worked and has no reliance on environment variables or ASP.NET Core so i the absolute best answer.

Comment: It may matter if the --environment arg is **first**.  This worked for me when it was first, but not always when it was not first.

Answer (score 35):

In **Visual Studio**, you can add an environment variable under the **Debug** tab of the console application properties. For a console application the *environment variable provider* name must be prefixed by *DOTNET_* for the generic host builder to recognize it.  In this case, the provider name is *DOTNET_ENVIRONMENT*.

[image: Visual Studio 2019 image]

If this provider name is not specified, the default is *Production*.

Reference : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/generic-host?view=aspnetcore-5.0#host-configuration

Comment: I think the answer could be improved by adding a little bit of code to get it to work:

.ConfigureHostConfiguration(configHost =>
{
  configHost.AddEnvironmentVariables(prefix: "DOTNET_");
}

Comment: @RobJohnston Your comment was actually the only thing on this page that truly answered this question for me.

Answer (score 17):

If you are using Visual Studio 2022 with .Net 5 and above, the UI could be a bit overwhelming. Its simple to edit launchSettings.json file under properties.

[image: LaunchSettings under properties]

Mine looks as follows. Note its `DOTNET_ENVIRONMENT` and **NOT** `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT` for .NET Core console app using Generic Host (HostBuilder)

```
{
  "profiles": {
    "Bvh.HrSita.DbMigrator": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "DOTNET_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    },
    "Bvh.HrSita.DbMigrator.Prod": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "DOTNET_ENVIRONMENT": "Production"
      }
    },
    "Bvh.HrSita.DbMigrator.Stag": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "DOTNET_ENVIRONMENT": "Staging"
      }
    },
    "Docker": {
      "commandName": "Docker"
    }
  }
}
```

Now select what ever profile you want when you launch the project. The following shows it all along with Program.cs.

[image: choosing launch profile in Visual Studio 2022]

And finally if you are trying to run the same in an Azure DevOps pipeline, the task should be as shown below. The arguments should have --environment Production. Note that adding env: is somehow **NOT** working for me as suggested [here](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/issues/11261#issuecomment-581885478).

```
    - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
      displayName: 'Run DbMigrator Project on the newly provisoned database'
      inputs:
        command: run
        projects: '$(Pipeline.Workspace)/$(finalBuildArtifactName)/src/Bvh.HrSita.DbMigrator/Bvh.HrSita.DbMigrator.csproj'
        arguments: '--configuration $(BuildConfiguration) --environment Production'
      env: 
        DOTNET_ENVIRONMENT: Production
```

Comment: Thanks! The _**DOTNET_ENVIRONMENT** and NOT **ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT** for .NET Core console app using Generic Host (HostBuilder)_ was the problem using the [Worker Service Template in .NET 6.0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/workers)

Comment: How do you add a launchSettings.json for a console app, as opposed to an ASP.NET Core app?

Comment: @SimonTewsi. Take a look at [this one](https://github.com/AvtsVivek/Elsa20StepByStepTuts/blob/90a9642e4a5f4865e1fb5900099f9a96fe275754/Elsa2.0Wf.Tuts/src/3_Persistance/P20445ContentApprovalPersistenceEfMsSql/Program.cs#L23) or [this](https://github.com/AvtsVivek/Elsa20StepByStepTuts/blob/90a9642e4a5f4865e1fb5900099f9a96fe275754/Elsa2.0Wf.Tuts/src/3_Persistance/P20447ContentApprovalPersistenceEfMsSqlWorkerHost/Program.cs#L15)

Comment: To answer my own question, I've since discovered that if I add an environment variable via the project Properties dialog as in Gary Chan's answer, https://stackoverflow.com/a/65804375/216440, it will automatically add a launchSettings.json file in the project Properties folder.  The environment variable will then be defined in the launchSettings.json file.  To avoid confusion, there are two ways of setting the environment via the project Properties dialog: via a command-line argument or via an environment variable.  I'm specifically talking about the environment variable here.

Comment: Thanks !!! When I changed ***ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT*** to ***DOTNET_ENVIRONMENT***  in my console application which is a hosted service application, the correct environment got picked.

Comment: @SimonElms you can even add it manually, but it will be created once you edit your project file (ALT + Enter), under Debug section and there is option Open debug launch profiles UI and it will shows you modal where you can add env variables. Of course I am talking about options in Visual Studio 2022.

Answer (score 11):

Another method is to use the "UseEnvironnement" method directly on the host builder :

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.hosting.hostinghostbuilderextensions.useenvironment?view=dotnet-plat-ext-5.0

For example :

```
   public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
            Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .UseEnvironment("dev") // Magic is here
                .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
                {
                    webBuilder.UseUrls("http://0.0.0.0:8081");
                    webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
                });
```

Comment: Please do not post images of code. Post the code as text in a code block.

Comment: Building off @JérémieLeclercq's comment to say you can plug in your env variable by passing the following into UseEnvironment(): "Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("DOTNET_ENVIRONMENT")"

Answer (score 11):

To add to pfx's accepted answer above, in **Visual studio 2022**, the environment variable can be set either via Properties window in UI:

[image]

or set the environment variable:

[image]

or directly edit the launchSettings.json file under Properties and add command line arguement:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

To pick up the hosting environment from environment variables, you can also add:

```
.ConfigureHostConfiguration(config =>
{
    config.AddEnvironmentVariables();
})
```

Then use `Environment` environment variable to pass the actual environment.

Answer (score 2):

In Visual Studio 2022 and .NET 6.0, appsettings.json and appsettings.[EnvironmentName].json are automatically included in configuration sources when using HostBuilder:

[image: Program.cs]

So there is no need to manually add these in ConfigureServices.

You still need to set EnvironmentName in launchSettings.json or as a commandline argument as shown in the other answers.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using visual studio and you have project configuration (Debug, Release, CustomUser...)
then you could include appsettings.[config-name].json like this:

```cs
Host
  .CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
  .ConfigureAppConfiguration((context, builder) => {
     //add visual studio configuration manager
     builder.AddJsonFile($"appSettings.{Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetCustomAttribute<AssemblyConfigurationAttribute>().Configuration}.json", true);
     ...
   })
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

I run into this issue time and time again and can never remember what my solution was from the previous time I ran into it. Typically, I'm simply trying to get a `Development` and `Production` environment in my console app like you get by default with a web app (configured with launchSettings.json and other more buried mechanisms).

At the beginning of my `Program.cs` in my console app, I add:

```
#if DEBUG
    Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("DOTNET_ENVIRONMENT", "Development");
#endif

var env = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("DOTNET_ENVIRONMENT") ?? "Production";
Console.WriteLine($"{env}");
```

However, you could also just as easily define your environment outright with the debug condition:

```
var env = "Production";
#if DEBUG
    env = "Development";
#endif
Console.WriteLine($"{env}");
```

You can also set your `EnvironmentName` like this:

```
 var host = Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
    .ConfigureAppConfiguration((context, config) =>
    {
        #if DEBUG
            context.HostingEnvironment.EnvironmentName = "Development";
        #endif

        var env = context.HostingEnvironment.EnvironmentName;
        Console.WriteLine(env);
  
        config.AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true)
            .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{env}.json", optional: true);    
    }).Build();
```

It's not command line, but should work as a solution. I also rarely see this suggested and found this digging through one of my older projects (after hours of searching online), so I'm not sure if it has any downsides (other than mostly only being good for one other environment besides Production)? Please leave a comment if there are other gotchas. It's definitely the easiest to implement for a console app.

Part of the reason for posting this answer also is so my future self can hopefully find it more quickly than this time around.